# Understanding the Sql Server execution time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using an SQL Server 2012 and `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` to measure the CPU-time for my sql statements. I use this because i only want to get the time the database needs to execute the statement.

When returning large data from a `select`, i noticed the CPU-time going up pretty high, like using `TOP 2000` will need about 400ms, but without it will need about 10000ms CPU-time.

**What i'm not sure about is**: 
Is it possible that the CPU-time i get returned includes something like the time it needs to display the millions of rows returned in my `Sql Server Management Studio`? That would be pretty much of a bad situation.

**Update:**

The time i want to recieve is the execution time of the sql server without the time needed for the ssms to display the rows. There are several time statistics display in the `Client statistics` , but after searching for a long time it's really hard to find good references explaining what they are. Any suggestions?

Idea: **elapsed time**(sql server execution time) **- client processing time** (Client statistics)

Maybe this is an option?

Comment: `TOP X` doesn't require the whole query to be evaluated for all data then discard all the unnecessary rows.  The lower cpu cost is because only the data needed to generate 2000 result rows are being processed.  If you're ***really*** conscious to prove that to yourself; look at the actual execution plan, and/or try inserting the results into a temporary table (no network traffic for the results, though there will still potentially be disk IO).

Comment: Are there ~50k records in your table?

Comment: i got around 100k rows

Answer (score 1):

In a multi-threaded world, CPU time is increasingly less helpful for simple tuning.  Execution time is worth looking at.

To see if execution time (elapsed time) spent on displaying results is included you could `SELECT TOP 2000 * INTO #temp` to compare execution times.

Update:

My quick tests suggest the overhead of creating/inserting into a #temp table outweighs that of displaying results (at 5000). When I go to 50,000 results the `SELECT INTO` runs more quickly.  The counts at which the two become equivalent depends on how many and what type of fields are returned. I tested with:

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
SELECT TOP 50000 NEWID()
FROM  master..spt_values v1, master..spt_values v2
WHERE v1.number > 100
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
-- CPU time = 32 ms,  elapsed time = 121 ms.


SET STATISTICS TIME ON
SELECT TOP 50000 NEWID() col1
INTO #test
FROM  master..spt_values v1, master..spt_values v2
WHERE v1.number > 100
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
-- CPU time = 15 ms,  elapsed time = 87 ms.
```

Comment: Thanks, i think thats the way to go. But isn't the `into #temp` producing execution time again?

Comment: @stb I just tested and yes, with just 2000 results the overhead from creating/inserting is greater than the overhead for returning results. See update.

Comment: We should be able to limit the displayed rows in ssms so this is not happening.

Comment: @stb I think it makes sense that output time is included in execution time, some forms of output are faster than others.

Comment: The thing is i am testing this against a database which returns the actual processing time without output. That makes it pretty hard to compare

Comment: But looks like i doing better by using a temp table

Comment: @stb You can also use Ctrl+L to "Include Client Statistics" in SSMS, the total execution time varies between that and the SET STATISTICS TIME ON results.

Comment: @GoatCO how are you ensuring that you have no caching between the queries?  Are you running them as posted here?

Comment: @DanAndrews i tried this several times and the first statement is always faster. So even if it's cached, the second is faster

Comment: WHAT?  Either way, I'm glad you found your solution.  I was just checking to see if @GoatCO knew of a trick to ensure different connections so that caching is not a factor. What I do is a hack, I run the 1st 2nd and the 2nd 1st in a different SID.  But I don't think it's the best way.

Comment: @DanAndrews Sorry, there was some mistake in this sentence. The `second` is always faster (sure maybe both got cached)

Answer (score 1):

CPU time in `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` only counts the time that SQL Server needs to execute the query. It doesn't include any time the client takes to render the results. It also excludes any time SQL Server spends waiting for buffers to clear. In short, it really is pretty independent of the client.

Comment: The problem CPU time is that it's the total time spent of all CPUs. Like 2000ms CPU time with 4 CPUs might take 500ms over all(2000/4) or most likely something between 500ms and 1000ms, because the CPUs don't work for the same time. I think it's just not possible to get what i want here